# org.gradle.api.GradleException: 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle

I have one Android project, which is giving this error on build:
I am getting this error:

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current >target is 19) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target >compatibility should be set to the same Java version.

build.gradle file

```
 android {
    namespace 'com.something'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.something"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 34
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
      // some configurations

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_19
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_19
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '19'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.7'
    }
}


dependencies {

   // some dependencies

}
```

As this is old project I cannot change gradle file properties, do I need to check any Android studio setting to remove this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different things, I checked Android Studio Settings.
After changing Gradle JDK to `corretto-19` my problem is solved.

Settings -> (Build, Execution, Deployment) -> (Build Tools) -> Gradle
Go to under Gradle JDK, choose `corretto-19`. Restart and build again